# Contact names not showing on dialer, but do show in Recents

Tags: samsung

Have a Samsung J3 2017 (SM327).  About a week ago, noticed that incoming & outgoing calls going to/from someone in my Contacts only shows the number, not the Contact name, so I often have no idea who's calling me.  But when I hang up and look in the Recent call log, the Contact name shows up correctly there.   I have tried every permission, every setting possible.  Spent an hour with an ATT tech - nothing.  Did a factory restore - nothing.  Took it to a Samsumg authorized serviced center and had it completely reflashed.   Fixed the prob for 2 days, then reappeared.   Any info?

Answer (score 2):

Found out source of problem.  It was ATT Call Protect app.  Disabled app and issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

- get a new phone :-P
- another app is handling the calls and lacks permission, could be yours or a virus. maybe try uninstalling/deactivating all apps until you find it. or start from scratch with the factory reset, add apps and check